# android: How to ExpandableListAdapter using the same class for group and child?

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to use android ExpandableListView widget. I have a class Item, it has many attributes about an item. I want my list to be look like, the elements of the group list only shows the name of the item, and some other important attributes. And when i click on the item, it expands and show all the attributes of the given item. So basically for me the group and the child element is the same, and my list which expands always has only one element. What is the proper way to write an Adapter for this. I tried something like this, but always gives me null pointer exeptions, when I want to expand an element.

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<VCDR> groups;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<VCDR>> children;


public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VCDR> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children= new ArrayList<ArrayList<VCDR>>();
    this.children.add(groups);

}


public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is kind of strange when you assign your groups ArrayList to the children multi-dimensional array in your constructor.  I would re-examine that.  Take a look at the example in the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Basically, you're going to have an array for your group headers (e.g. Header 1, Header 2, etc).  And in your children multi-dimensional array, you want to assign your attributes accordingly for each header of your group array.

The documentation gives this example:

```
    private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
            { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
            { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
            { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
    };
```

So, for 'People Names', you'd look at the array contained in the 0 index of the children object ... Arnold, Barry, Chuck, etc.  This could easily be rewritten to use an ArrayList as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm managed to do, what I was trying to do. I'm not sure is it a proper way, but it seems to work. As all my data to display is in the same class, I only use one ArrayList. It basicly a view - detailed view app. The group only has one child, itself. Do you think it is ok that way? Or I might experience inconsistensy issues later with this implementation?

```
public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VCDR> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;        
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {      
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}
```